# TFS 2008 - Renaming proj files and merging it back to the trunk-

Tags: tfs

I am renaming all the project files in a solution and merging it back to the trunk. I will explain the scenario and would like to know what will be the best practice to achieve that.

Trunk -  Solution1.sln

```
- XXX.proj
- XXX_VS2008.proj
```

Branch -
   Solution1.sln

```
 - XXX.proj
 - XXX_VS2008.proj
```

For some reason during a migration from 2005 to 2008 the project files where renamed with a suffix VS2008. Now we are doing a migration to 2010 and want to get rid of the suffix.

What I have done is deleted the XXX.proj in the branch, checked in and renamed the XXX_VS2008.proj to XXX.proj.

Now when I merge it back to the trunk I get problems as TFS has to delete XXX.proj file and rename XXX_VS2008 to XXX.proj at the same time.

What would have been a better approach for this kind of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't delete and rename, but overwrite the content XXX.proj with the content of XXX_VS2008 and delete teh XXX_2008 proejct file and checkin the modified XXX.proj file.

Comment: XXX_VS2008 is currently being used by all developers and XXX is made obsolete in the main trunk. If I delete XXX_VS2008 and override XXX in the branch while merging I will lose the changes done to XXX_VS2008 in the Main trunk while I was working in the branch.